# How to keep groups in pandas groupby when value is consective 1 for 4 times

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I want to groupby my dataframe and check if in each column value of flag column remains 1 consecutively equal or greater than 2 rows in group then keep this group if group count is less than   for consecutive 1 remove from dataframe

```
dataframe1=pd.DataFrame({'x1':[5,678,78,89,4,5,6,5],'x2':[555,555,555,555,3,3,3,3],'flag':[1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0]}) 

df_out=dataframe1=pd.DataFrame({'x1':[5,678],'x2':[555,555],'flag':[1,1]})


i can use groupby :

df_out=dataframe1.groupby(by='x2')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cumsum()` on the non-zero difference to identify the flag blocks:

```
blocks = dataframe1.flag.diff().ne(0).cumsum()
sizes = blocks.groupby([dataframe1['X2'],blocks]).transform('size')

dataframe1[dataframe1['flag'].eq(1) & sizes.ge(2)]
```

Output:

```
    x1   x2  flag
0    5  555     1
1  678  555     1
```

Comment: I want to do groupby X2

Comment: @Edward check updated answer with `'X2'` in `groupby`.

Comment: key error X2 , because its not in blocks how we can do groupby by x2

Comment: Sorry, my bad, it's `dataframe1['X2']`.

Answer (score 1):

Find the consecutive differences in flag in each group. If NaN, make it zero. Sum up the difference and if equal or less than 2, pick it up.

```
 s=dataframe1[dataframe1['flag'].eq(1)]#Filter 1s
 
 s[s.groupby('x2')['flag'].transform(lambda x: (x.diff().fillna(0).eq(0).sum())).ge(2)]#Filter the consecutive as stated



    x1   x2  flag
0    5  555     1
1  678  555     1
```

Comment: with your this line of code can not get this result that you show here , please can you check again

Comment: Please see my edits. Happy to help further

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(dd: pd.DataFrame):
    if len(dd) > 1 and dd.flag.eq(1).all():
        return dd

col1 = dataframe1.flag.ne(dataframe1.flag.shift()).cumsum()
dataframe1.groupby(col1,group_keys=False).apply(function1)
```

Output:

```
    x1   x2  flag
0    5  555     1
1  678  555     1
```